# How to separate variables in DiffEq of $y'=x-y$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = x-y$$

How do I separate so I can integrate both sides?
Thanks for getting me started.

I know the solution is $$ y = x-1+2e^{-x}$$

Comment: The equation is not separable. It _is_ a _linear_ first-order DE; presumably how to solve linear DEs was covered in class before this  problem was assigned...

Comment: The initial condition is missing.

Answer (score 2):

Let $y=x+z$. The equation becomes
$$z'+1=-z,$$

which is separable.

> $$\frac{z'}{z+1}=-1,\\\log(z+1)=C-x,\\z=Ce^{-x}-1,\\\color{green}{y=Ce^{-x}+x-1}.$$

Comment: Where did you get $y=x+z$ from?   And how did you get $z'+1=-z$ ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Your equation is $$y'(x)+y(x)=x.$$

Multiply both side by $e^x$ gives $$\big(y(x)e^x\big)'=xe^x.$$

I let you conclude.

Answer (score 0):

You can't separate. If you want to make it separable you can notice the equation is homogeneous and use the substitution $vx=Y$.

Otherwise, if you know how to solve linear differential equations, turn this into $y'+y=x$. The integrating factor is just $e^x$. So we have $\frac{d}{dx}(e^x y) = xe^x$.

Integrate with respect to $x$ and you get $(x-1)e^x + C = ye^x \Rightarrow  y=x-1+Ce^{-x}$

Comment: $y=vx$ doesn't make the equation separable.

Comment: Yes I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}+y=x \implies e^{-x}\frac{d}{dx} y e^x=x \implies  \int d (e^{x}y)= \int  xe^{x} dx$$ $$ \implies y e^{x} =- e^x+xe^x + C \implies y=(x-1)+Ce^{-x}.$$

Comment: You integrated xe^x incorrectly.

Comment: I have corrected it now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}+y = x$$
Solve the homogeneous equation
$$y'+y=0 \implies (\ln y)'=-1 \implies y=c_1e^{-x}$$
For the particular solution try
$$y_p=Ax+B$$
You forgot to write the initial condition. That's why you don't have a constant $c_1$ in the solution you provided.

Answer (score 0):

this is LDE

let me explain how to solve this

first of all you have to compare the given DE with LDE

$ {dy} / {dx} + P(x) y = Q(x) $

solving process

INTEGRAL FACTOR (I.F)= $e^{∫ P(x)dx} $

the solution is

$ y I.F = ∫{Q(x)} I.F dx +c $

now we have from given

DE

${dy}/{dx} +y=x $

$P(x) = 1 , Q(x) = x$

I.F = $ e^{∫{1} dx} = e^{x} $

the general solution is

$ y  e^{x} = ∫ { x e^{x}} dx +c $

$y e^{x} = e^{x} [ x -1] + c $

$ y = x-1+ce^{-x} $

Answer (score 0):

### Hint:

differentiate the equation to get
$$y''=1-y'$$
$$\frac{y''}{y'-1}=-1$$