# Equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=y-x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider an equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=y - x$. Is there a solution to this? If so, will it have a local mininum along $y=x$? Sorry if the question is not specific, this is the best I can phrase it, and I don't really understand how to approach the problem.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3558401/42969

Comment: One way to do it is to assume that $y$ is given by a Maclaurin series.

Comment: Please do not ask us to do your work for you, when you bring absolutely nothing to the table.  We are not a do-it-for-me service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we write it as
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}-y=-x \, ,
$$
then we are dealing with a linear first-order differential equation of the form
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}+p(x)y=q(x) \, .
$$
To solve an equation of this form, you have to multiply both sides by $e^{P(x)}$, where $P$ is an antiderivative of $p$. Here $p(x)=-1$, and so we can take $P(x)=-x$. The equation becomes
$$
e^{-x}\frac{dy}{dx}-ye^{-x}=-xe^{-x} \\
\frac{d}{dx}(e^{-x}y)=-xe^{-x} \, .
$$
Integrating both sides and rearranging gives you the answer.